# Run Ansible module module multiple time

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want to do the following:

```
---
- name: install stuff
  hosts: h1
  tasks:
  - name: install stuffs
    tags: install_stuffs
    apt:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      update_cache: yes
    shell: |    # multiline string, right?
      apt-key bla_bla
    apt:
      name: other_package
    vars:
      packages:
      - python3
      - nano
```

However, Ansible reports that the `apt` is duplicated. Why is that? Does YAML treat my `task` (named `install stuff`) a dictionary? And how to achieve what I want: `apt` then run some command then `apt`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Does YAML treat my task (named install stuff) a dictionary?

Yes

> And how to achieve what I want: apt then run some command then apt?

You need to split these steps out into separate tasks:

```
---
- name: install stuff
  hosts: h1
  tasks:
  - name: install stuffs
    tags: install_stuffs
    apt:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      packages:
      - python3
      - nano

  - name: run stuff
    shell: apt-key bla_bla

  - name: install more stuff
    apt:
      name: other_package
```